# Banach Spaces: Uniform Integral vs. Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given a finite measure space $\Omega$ and a Banach space $E$.

> One has strict inclusion:
>   $$\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{U}(\mu)\subsetneq\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}(\mu):\quad\int_\mathfrak{U}F\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu$$
>   How to prove this from scratch?

**Uniform Integral**

Predefine the simple integral:
$$S=\sum_kb_k\chi(A_k):\quad\int_\mathfrak{S}S\mathrm{d}\mu:=\sum_k b_k\mu(A_k)$$

It is uniformly bounded:
$$\|\int_\mathfrak{S}S\mathrm{d}\mu\|\leq\|S\|_\infty\mu(\Omega)$$
So define the uniform integral by:
$$F=\lim_nS_n:\quad\int_\mathfrak{U}F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_n\int_\mathfrak{S}S_n\mathrm{d}\mu$$
*(More precisely, by the a.e. uniform closure!)*

**Riemann Integral**

Define the Riemann integral by:
$$\int_\mathfrak{R}F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_\mathcal{P}\{\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)\}_\mathcal{P}$$
Finite measurable partitions:
$$\mathcal{P}\subseteq\Sigma:\quad\Omega=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{P}}A\quad(\#\mathcal{P}<\infty)$$
Order them by refinement:
$$\mathcal{P}\leq\mathcal{P}':\iff\forall A'\in\mathcal{P}'\exists A\in\mathcal{P}:\quad A\supseteq A'$$
*(That is the usual ordering.)*

Comment: Example: $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(\frac{1}{n+1}<x\leq\frac{1}{n}):=q_n\quad(q_n\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1])$

Comment: If you are taking the **uniform** limit (and not the $L^\infty (\mu)$-limit) in the first case, then every function integrable w.r.t. the first definition is bounded, whereas for the second definition, we only need $f \in L^\infty (\mu)$. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @PhoemueX: No I intended the almost everywhere uniform limit ($\mathcal{L}^\infty$) but I kept it short so it won't get messy (I hoped it will be clear from the context). Will add a note now!

Comment: @PhoemueX: Got it! :D *(See below.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ok, I think I got it now...*

**Strictness**

Consider the famous example:
$$F:(0,1]\to\ell^2(0,1]:t\mapsto\chi_t$$

Then it can't be uniform limit as:
$$\|\chi_s-\chi_t\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\quad(s\neq t)$$

Choose the partition:
$$\mathcal{P}\geq\mathcal{P}_\varepsilon:=\left\{\left(\frac{k-1}{K(\varepsilon)},\frac{k}{K(\varepsilon)}\right]:k=1,\ldots,K(\varepsilon)\right\}$$

So it is Riemann integrable as:
$$\|\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}\chi(a)\lambda(A)\|^2=\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}\lambda(A)^2\leq\frac{1}{K(\varepsilon)}\lambda(0,1]<\varepsilon$$
*(Besides, its Riemann integral vanishes.)*

**Inclusion**

Consider a uniform limit:
$$S_n\in\mathcal{S}:\quad S_n\to F$$

Choose a simple function:
$$S_{N(\varepsilon)}=\sum_{k=1}^{K}b_k\chi(A_k):\quad\|F-S_{N(\varepsilon)}\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2\mu(\Omega)}$$

Choose the partition: 
$$\mathcal{P}\geq\mathcal{P}_\varepsilon:=\{A_1,\ldots,A_{K}\}$$

Then for finer partitions:
$$\|\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)-\int_\mathfrak{U}F\mathrm{d}\mu\|\\
\leq\|\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)-\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}S_N(a)\mu(A)\mathrm{d}\mu\|+\|\int_\mathfrak{S}S_{N}\mathrm{d}\mu-\int_\mathfrak{U}F\mathrm{d}\mu\|\\
\leq\|F-S_N\|_\infty\mu(\Omega)+\|F-S_N\|_\infty\mu(\Omega)<\varepsilon$$

Especially, the integrals coincide.

**Supplementary**

Another potential example is given in: [Stone's Theorem Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004930/79762)

Comment: I don't have much time right now, but: **Every** bounded measurable function is the uniform limit of simple functions (if we allow "steps" that are arbitrary measurable sets, not just intervals (which would give Riemann step functions)). This would indicate that your counterexample is not a counterexample.

Comment: Hmmm, right ...

Comment: @PhoemueX: I think I got it now. Can you check quickly?

Comment: I really don't understand the downvote. Does somebody have an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I only looked over everything quickly, but it seems good to me especially the first part (especially that the Riemann integral vanishes) is interesting.

Comment: Yes, me too. I found it some time ago in: [V. Kadets, Some Remarks on Strong Vector-Valued Integration (Example on Page 2)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9903103)