# Generalized Riemann Integral: Bounded Nonexample?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

**Reference**

For a convergence theorem on integral see: [Riemann Integral: Uniform Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041475/79762)

For an improper version of integral see: [Riemann Integral: Improper Version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1039802/79762)

For a comparison of integrals see: [Uniform Integral vs. Riemann Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017558/79762)

**Definition**

Given a finite measure space $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and a Banach space $E$.

Consider functions $F:\Omega\to E$.

Define the generalized Riemann integral by:
$$\int F\mathrm{d}\mu:=\lim_\mathcal{P}\{\sum_{a\in A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)\}_\mathcal{P}$$
over finite measurable partitions:
$$\mathcal{P}\subseteq\Sigma:\quad\Omega=\bigsqcup_{A\in\mathcal{P}}A\quad(\#\mathcal{P}<\infty)$$
being ordered by refinement:
$$\mathcal{P}\leq\mathcal{P}':\iff\forall A'\in\mathcal{P}'\exists A\in\mathcal{P}:\quad A\supseteq A'$$
*(In fact, the tags are just surpressed.)*

**Discussion**

What do nonintegrable functions look like?
$$F:\Omega\to E:\quad F\notin\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}(\mu)$$
Obviously, nonmeasurable nonexamples are countless:
$$\mu^*(V)\neq\mu_*(V):\quad F=\chi_V$$
Also, a.e. boundedness is a necessary condition on integrability:
$$F\notin\mathcal{L}^\infty(\mu)\implies F\notin\mathcal{L}_\mathfrak{R}(\mu)$$
So are there bounded measurable nonexamples?
*(Note that continuity is not an accessible concept here.)*

Besides, pathological examples like the Dirichlet function become integrable.

**Deep Consequence**

Riemann integrability is not guaranted by absolute integrabilit alone:
$$\int\|F\|\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty\nRightarrow \int F\mathrm{d}\mu\in E$$
But this shouldn't be to big surprise as this wasn't either the case for Bochner integrability.

Comment: Probably any nonmeasurable function (modulo equality a.e. or w.r.t. the completion of the measure space) will not be "Riemann"-integrable. BTW: I am still thinking about your related question.

Comment: Oh nice. :) So it's still missing wether uniform implies Riemann.

Comment: Yeah thought so too like $\chi_A$ for $A\notin\hat{\Sigma}$. I will add the assumption of measurability. So but how about measurables?

Comment: @PhoemueX: If you're still interested, see below. ;) Banach-space valued function: Bounded and measurable (though separable valued nor totally bounded) but **not** Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ok, I think I got it now...*

Take a slight variation of the famous example:
$$F:[0,1]\to\ell[0,1]:t\mapsto\chi_t$$

At least, it is bounded: $\|F(t)\|\equiv1$.

Especially, it is absolutely integrable: $\int\|F(t)\|\mathrm{d}t=1$

However, it is not measurable as:
$$\|\chi_s-\chi_t\|^2=2\quad(s\neq t)$$
so taking a Vitali set yields:
$$U:=\bigcup_{v\in V}B_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}(\chi_v):\quad U\in\mathcal{T}[0,1],F^{-1}U=V\notin\mathcal{B}[0,1]\quad\left(V\subseteq[0,1]\right)$$

Moreover, it has nonseparable range:
$$\|\chi_s-\chi_t\|\equiv2\quad(s\neq t)$$
So it can't be pointwise limit in any case: $S_n\nrightarrow F$

Finally, it is not Riemann integrable as:
$$\|\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a)\mu(A)-\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}}F(a')\mu(A)\|=\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}}\|\chi_a-\chi_{a'}\|\mu(A)=2\sum_{A\in\mathcal{P}}\mu(A)\equiv2\mu(\Omega)\quad(a\neq a')$$