# Nonmeasurable Functions

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

**Reference**

This question is related to: [Banach Spaces: Uniform Integral vs. Riemann Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017558/79762)

**Problem**

What are examples of real-valued functions:

Bounded & Non-Step & Non-Measurable

*(Especially, it should be not a.e. a step!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It is still quite trivial but at least...*

Given the Lebesgue measure $\lambda:[0,1]\to(0,\infty)$.

Consider a Vitali set $\mu_*(V)<\mu^*(V)$.

Construct the function:
$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f(x):=x^2\chi_V(x)$$
This one is not sum of measurable plus step but product.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a non-measurable set, it must be uncountable, select a countable points from it $\{x_i\}$, define $f=\chi_V$ except those points, and let $f(x_i)=\frac{1}{n}$.

So $f$ is bounded by $1$, unmeasurable, has countable many values.

Comment: That is still to simple as you can subtract a bounded measurable function from it to get it piecewise-constant.

Comment: If singletons are measurable then the one restricted to the countable many points.

Comment: @JohnZHANG You can add a function which is $1-1/n$ at $x_n$ and $0$ elsewhere to get back an indicator function. Such a function is measurable, since its support has measure zero and the Lebesgue measure is complete.